# List Sort Not Producing Expected Result

Tags: c#

I have a List which appears not be sorting properly.  To find out what is happening I have added code:

```
    // save unsorted list
    using (StreamWriter listfile = new StreamWriter("D:\\UnsortedList.csv", 
    false))
    {
        foreach (string currentLine in FileList)
        {
            listfile.WriteLine(currentLine);
        }
        listfile.Close();
    }
```

I then sort it and save the result to another file:-

```
FileList.Sort();
// save sorted list
using (StreamWriter listfile = new 
StreamWriter("D:\\UnfilteredFileList.csv", false))
{
    foreach (string currentLine in FileList)
    {
        listfile.WriteLine(currentLine);
    }
listfile.Close();
}
```

The first unsorted file contains some lines (line numbers added by me):

```
1   attributes\53.p_40NB MED 90º ELBOW,zipped
2   attributes\6.00 B02 level.PObjGrp,zipped
3   attributes\6.00- B02 level.PObjGrp,zipped
4   attributes\6.01- B02 level.PObjGrp,zipped
5   attributes\6.02- B03 level.PObjGrp,zipped
..........
6   attributes\53.p_40NB MED 90º ELBOW,folder
7   attributes\6.00 B02 level.PObjGrp,folder
8   attributes\6.00- B02 level.PObjGrp,folder
9   attributes\6.01- B02 level.PObjGrp,folder
10  attributes\6.02- B03 level.PObjGrp,folder
```

After the sort I expected line 7 to end up before 2.  Instead I got:

```
attributes\53.p_40NB MED 90º ELBOW,zipped
attributes\6.00 B02 level.PObjGrp,folder
attributes\6.00- B02 level.PObjGrp,folder
attributes\6.00 B02 level.PObjGrp,zipped
attributes\6.00- B02 level.PObjGrp,zipped
attributes\6.01- B02 level.PObjGrp,folder
```

Am I misunderstanding sorting?

Comment: line 7 did go before line 2, isnt that what you expect?

Comment: are you keeping in mind that the **sort**, the way you are using it, is a  lexicographic sort ? if you want anything other than that you'll need to pull, parse, whatever those lines into some structure where a custom numeric sort can be applied.

Answer (score 3):

The internal string comparer [compares string by words](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Compare_System_String_System_String_), so use an affirmatory comparer like:

```
FileList.Sort(string.CompareOrdinal);
```